# Проверка в коде текущего времени

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужно проверить в коде какое сейчас  время. Я взял время с сайта http://www.unn.ru/time/, но условие не работает

```
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token = '5458464422:AAGson7WC_ZiO-NAuTVZ6qCK9yVSXQzVujw'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


url = 'http://www.unn.ru/time/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
minute = soup.findAll('div', {'id' : 'servertime'})[0].text

money = 0

print(minute)
if minute[5] == 5:
    money += 10
    print(money)

bot.polling()
```

minute[5] - это минуты единицы, то есть 09:31, здесь это 1.

Другими словами, мне нужно сделать часовой доход в игре. Каждый час деньги должны прибавляться, может есть другой способ это сделать, я не знаю.

Comment: замените `minute[5] == '5'`. только зачем запрос в интернет для времени? используйте datetime

Comment: Мы не ищем лёгких путей? Чем вас время из [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) не устраивает?

Comment: парсить время, сильно

Comment: Лучше уж по `NTP` время брать тогда, например через `ntplib`.